# How to conditionally update react list components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the React app below ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skainet/56w2zp1q/23/)):

```js
const ListItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.active ? "active" : ""}>Item {props.index}</div>
  )
}

const initialItems = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]

const App = (props) => {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const goUp = () => {
    if(activeIndex <= 0) return;

    setActiveIndex(activeIndex - 1);
  }

  const goDown = () => {
    if(activeIndex >= initialItems.length - 1) return;

    setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
  }

    return (
    <div>
      <p>
        <button onClick={goUp}>Up</button>
        <button onClick={goDown}>Down</button>
      </p>
      <div>
        {initialItems.map((item, index) => (
            <ListItem active={index === activeIndex} index={index} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Using buttons you can highlight the current list element. The issue with the current approach is that on every active index change it re-renders the full list. In my case, the list might be very big (hundreds of items) with a more complicated layout, which introduces performance problems.

How might this code be modified so it updates only specific list item components and doesn't trigger re-render of all others? I'm looking for a solution without third-party libraries and without direct DOM manipulations.

Comment: There are manual workarounds (like memoize `ListItem`), but seems like you want [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized)

Comment: i think you shoud use purecomponent in your react-app you can read about purecomponent in this link (https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html)

Comment: As I know, since you used key in your list, React cleverly manages this and don't re-render full list. How do you checked if the full list re-renders?

Comment: @SuleymanSah if you put a breakpoint on ListItem component, it will call render every time active index changes (for all items). I added a console.log to indicate the problem.

Comment: @Kai,  yes component will re-render every time when state changes, but it does not mean React will re-render the full list in the dom. You can check this in browser developer tools. Re-rendering is not a problem as long as it renders fast.

Comment: Yes, but it's not efficient if I have hundreds of List items with some logic (even in case if React doesn't toch the DOM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap ListItem with React.memo() as [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate).

This is your ListItem component,

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.active ? "active" : ""}>Item {props.index}</div>
  )
};
```

By using React.Memo(),

```
const ListItem = React.memo((props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.active ? "active" : ""}>Item {props.index}</div>
  )
});
```

In this case `ListItem` is only rendered when props gets changed.

See for [updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLw7qtod/1/) and check with console.log() s.

Comment: But I've checked and it seems that's something I was looking for

Comment: Check now for the updat. Check for the console.log messages.